# Create a string object with the string '/ObjC/GNUstep/mingw/bin'

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Create a string object with the string '/ObjC/GNUstep/mingw/bin'

Print each component in the path:

```
ObjC
GNUstep
mingw
bin
```

how to do this,am not able to exclude "/" while printing,plz help

Comment: Mate, you didn't even _try_ to disguise the fact that this is homework :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) Class Reference for this, specifically 'Working with the Paths' Section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is homework in which case the point is to learn algorithms. That means no fancy class library functions (that negate the algorithm learning) and pseudo-code only (so you won't get caught out for plagiarism):

```
string s = "/ObjC/GNUstep/mingw/bin"

# Output the first character if it's not '/'
#   ('if' to prevent mishandling empty strings).

if s.len() > 0:
    if s[0] != "/":
        output s[0]

# Output all other character except last, translating '/' into newline
#   ('if' prevents mishandling strings two chars or less).

if s.len() > 2:
    for i goes from 1 to s.len()-2:
        if s[i] == "/":
            output newline
        else:
            output s[i]

# Output last character if not '/' 
#   ('if' is to prevent mishandling one-char strings)

if s.len() > 1:
    if s[s.len()-1] != "/":
        output s[s.len()-1]

output newline
```